# Installing WWW::Mechanize – Error GETing localhost: Can't connect to localhost

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, www-mechanize

I am using the command

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install WWW::Mechanize'
```

to try and install WWW::Mechanize on macOS, and kept getting the error

```
1/13 Error GETing http://localhost:51623/: Can't connect to localhost:51623 (Connection refused) at t/local/referer.t line 39.
```

I somewhat fixed this by changing the file /etc/hosts by adding a -v6 at the end of the second instance of the word "localhost". /etc/hosts now reads

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost-v6
```

Now, at the end of the installation process, I get this Test Summary Report:

```
t/live/wikipedia.t     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=58, Tests=608, 69 wallclock secs ( 0.25 usr  0.11 sys +  8.25 cusr  1.28 csys =  9.89 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/58 test programs. 0/608 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.78.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.78.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

How can I install WWW::Mechanize?

Comment: When I first configured cpan, I did not give it permission to write in the system's perl installation. Rather, it created a new folder: /users/(me)/Perl5, where I have been installing modules so far.

Comment: Then you shouldn't need `sudo`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Ah ok, I was just using a command I found on the internet for installing modules. I get the same result with or without `sudo`. More importantly, is this error (`t/live/wikipidia.t`) something I can force install over safely? (Also, how would I force install using this command?)

Comment: The module error matrix shows no problem with OSX http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/WWW-Mechanize.html#WWW-Mechanize-1.78 It must be a problem with the local configuration. Try to open some webserver in that port, 51623, and see if you can access it. Maybe it's closed by a firewall or otherwise restricted, but my point is that you should check your local configuration, it does not seem to be a general problem.

Comment: It looks like you're having problems with networking generally. The mech test suite is now quite extensive and try access live websites (wikipedia) as well as running and checking things on your local machine (the localhost:51623 stuff). If you use a firewall/proxy you may have to provide credentials to allow access to such things. You can install via the normal method, skipping the tests if you want, however since you likely want to use the module with sites it's more likely you want to resolve the general issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (only) failed test I get when installing without force failed due to the certificate authenticity of the wikipedia page that was being used. After force installing WWW::Mechanize, the module works fine.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't need IP v6, remove it from your 'hosts' file. But to me doesn't make any sense CPAN are trying to get modules from 'localhost' because of this. Anyways, remove that 'ip v6 thing' from your host and try again, please!